# How to improve performance of an application which creates a lot objects with multi-threading?

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance

I am writing a C# SDK for a NoSQL database, and to handle the requests (etc. serialize or unserialize, signature) I have to create a lot (small) objects.

I tested the performance of this new SDK in a simple program which created a specified number of threads and cycle call the APIs as playload in each thread. With 1 thead, the QPS hits 6K+, but as the thread number increasing, the overall QPS decreased instead of multipled.

To find out why, I simplified my test program and reduce the payload into a very simple code instead of actually call my SDK interface:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i ++) {
    double a = Math.Pow(3.14, 0.5);
}
```

The performance result is quite OK:

> 1 thread 132 QPS
>   2 threads 261 QPS
>   4 threads 1028 QPS
>   8 threads 1826 QPS

But when I changed the payload into:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i ++) {
    var c = new string('X', 50);
}
```

The performance looks like this:

> 1 thread 300 QPS
>   2 threads 497 QPS
>   4 threads 596 QPS
>   8 threads 518 QPS

And the result will be the same (not linear) if I create some other objects in the payload.

(Both of the above cases did not reach the CPU and memory limit)

Why? And my SDK will naturally creates a objects so is there a way to work around?

Some of my guesses:

1. The memory allocation of .NET framework has a performance bottlenet so when you create objects parallely you will suffer.
2. The GC of .NET framework starts to work and dramatically reduced the performance.

Comment: threads are not cheap. How are you creating these new threads? Are you taking advantage of asynchronous IO?

Comment: @Tejas In the 2 cases I didn't do anything involving asynchronous  .  In the main thread I create 1 - 8 threads to cycly call my SDK interface and wait for them to finish.

Comment: *generally*, if you are going to be doing sustained high allocations, you would investigate tools like object pools and re-use -  done *sensibly and appropriately* (not too overkill), you can shave vast amounts of allocations and collections - but you don't want to take it too far, as doing tthis can also artificially fragment the memory space. But sure: allocations aren't *free*, even if they are *cheap*

Comment: @MarcGravell  I know allocations aren't free, but will they become more expensive in multi-thread scenario? My question here is how to make performance increase linearly by threads.

Comment: Not really. The collections are more likely to blame rather than the allocations. Reusing objects and using value types where appropriate will go a long way towards better performance. But you *have* to profile the code to find the real bottlenecks.

Comment: Is there an explanation for the performance of my second case?

Comment: Sure. Hugely oversimplifying, in the first case, the `double` value lives on the stack (or perhaps even just a register) - it has no associated allocation nor clean-up cost. In the second case, the `string` value lives on the heap. Even though you're not actually using it anywhere, the only way to "deallocate" it is by doing a full GC collection - which freezes all your threads while traversing the heap. Since you're not actually doing anything but allocating and collecting objects, this will tend to dominate the benchmark results.

Comment: So the first case actually does scale linearly, because it's purely CPU work with hardly any overheads and no synchronization. The second case is completely different, because its performance depends pretty much completely on the way the garbage *collection* works - it doesn't actually do any "real" work. You might be able to tweak the performance by playing around with GC settings (there's various ways to improve throughput while increasing latency and vice versa, and there's different GCs available nowadays, depending on your .NET version and configuration).

Comment: I think I got your idea. @Luaan I will try to profile my code and make appropriate reusing (using value types is hard in my scenario). I will let you know if the result is good.

Comment: In my experience, `string`s are often to blame - those are also quite hard to "reuse" (most string operations aren't available on `StringBuilder` nor `char[]`). You'll also probably have quite a lot of `byte[]` operations - those are a lot easier, though it still needs care. But you'll get a lot more exact information from a profiler - find out what's the things that are collected most often, often you'll get a nice call graph or at least an object graph to see who allocated them and why.

Comment: I don't know if playing around with GC settings is a good idea. Because the SDK will be shipped to end users and my good performance with local settings means nothing to them because they use default configuration.

Comment: I do have a lot `byte[]` operations because I am using `protobuf-csharp-port`. Could you say more about it? What kind of special care?

Comment: @Haowei until you've actually *profiled*, this is a guessing game; yes, allocations can be a problem, [but there are ways of addressing that](http://blog.marcgravell.com/2011/10/assault-by-gc.html), if  needed. Pooling is another big approach, as I mentioned. I find it interesting that you mention protobuf, as that's *also* an area I dabble in - and protobuf-net maintains micro-pools internally for things like working buffers.

Comment: @MarcGravell I did some profiling before, and found some hot spot like `MD5.Create()`. If it is meant to be, I will use pooling for them. I use `protobuf-csharp-port` because we have a `.proto` file defined in the first place and with `protobuf-csharp-port` I can generate code instead of redefine the data model all the way through.

Answer (score 0):

The main rule for the multithreading programming is that you shouldn't create threads more than your `CPU cores + 1`. This is because then you've created many threads, they all trying to get their work done simultaneously, and your CPU and OS lowers the performance by the `context switching`. This is very time-consuming operation - better to do two pieces of work in the same thread than one piece of work by two threads.

There are a lot of techniques to improve the performance of your application, for example, [work stealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_stealing), but you should investigate that by yourself as this is very broad topic.

Comment: Well, my computer has 24 CPU cores and I only starts at most 8 threads. So it's not my case.